# Possible to determine usage stats for other iPhone/iPad apps?

Tags: ios

I'm an iOS newbie, but was wondering if it's possible to use a built-in API to determine how much time another app was active during some period (say, the last 24 hours).  I don't have access to the source code for the other app.

I'm guessing that security precautions in iOS make this impossible, but wanted to see if anyone else had suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't and can't get usage data of other apps on the system, unless you own those apps or have a formal relationship with the developer of said app.

Comment: this is what i was worried about.  thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Google Analytics for iOS

http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Flurry API allows you to track a number of things and report back.  You might start with something like that. There are a number of Analytics solutions.